# PDF encoded in base64, how to decode it?

Tags: vb.net, pdf, encoding, base64, decode

I have an encoded PDF in base64.

```
Dim pdf As String = ""
pdf = x.SIOrderPDF(apiKey, UserHash, tablicaZlecen, "pl").pdf  'this method returns a string pdf encoded in base64
```

Here is my question, how to decode it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is all you need: http://www.example-code.com/vb/base64-encode-decode.asp

In order to comply with the request written in the comment of this answer I also copied all the code form the link above to here:

```
Dim crypt As New ChilkatCrypt2
crypt.CryptAlgorithm = "none"
crypt.EncodingMode = "base64"
Dim strBase64 As String
strBase64 = crypt.EncryptStringENC(s)

Text1.Text = Text1.Text & strBase64 & vbCrLf

Dim decoded As String
decoded = crypt.DecryptStringENC(strBase64)
```

Comment: Please do not provide link-only answer. As link may not be accessible anytime in the future.